# Custom MailComposeViewController Navigationbar not working in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Developing MFMailComposeViewController to have custom titleView on the navigationBar on ios 5 Simulator but it does not work on it.
Currently it has Xcode 4.2 and when deployed on iOS 4, it works correctly but not on iOS 5.
How to resovle the issue since the method is not depracated still ?

```
MFMailComposeViewController* mailComposeViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        mailComposeViewController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorNavTint];
        mailComposeViewController.navigationBar.topItem.titleView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
mailComposeViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorNavTint];
mailComposeViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.titleView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]] autorelease];
```

**Edit:**
 Try this:
`mailComposeViewController.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView=[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]] autorelease];`